# Upload files into GDrive then delete locally

Tags: windows, backup, sync, google-drive

Is there any settings in Gdrive windows Sync app, or any other third party app that allows auto uploading file to GDrive then delete the local file.
The idea behind the deleting is to protect the files against ransomware encrypting

Ps: in Android, [MetaaCTRL Drive Sync App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.drivesync) allows this functionality

Answer (score 0):

As I see you need to backup the source data to Google Drive then delete the copied data from the source, tons of third-party tools can do this task easily, you could take a look at GoodSync, Gs Richcopy360, or Carbonite, try the trial versions first